# Unable to generate table after clearing table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, dom-events

I'm working on a project but am stuck on the fact that I'm unable to generate a new table after resetting the previous table.

What I would like to do is to let a user reset the table using the button and then generate another one if needed, and not needing him to reload the page. However, I am unsure why my codes only allow me to reset the table but am unable to generate another table.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function generate() {

  var myTable = document.getElementById("generatedTable");

  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border = '1';

  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  var rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;
  var cols = document.getElementById("cols").value;

  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {

    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');

      td.width = 10;
      td.height = 10;

      var cellID = "cell [" + x + ", " + y + "]";
      td.setAttribute("id", cellID.toString());

      td.addEventListener("click", function() {
        cellClicked(this);
      });

      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + x + "," + y));

      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    myTable.appendChild(table);


  }

  //document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;


}

function cellClicked(cell) {

  //var cell = document.getElementById("this");
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";


}

function mouseOver(cell) {
  var cell = document.getElementById("td");
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function mouseOut(cell) {
  var cell = document.getElementById("generatedTable");
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function removeTable() {
  var removeTab = document.getElementById('generatedTable');
  var parentElement = removeTab.parentElement;
  parentElement.removeChild(removeTab);

}
```

```html
No. of Rows <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows">
<br>
<br> No. of Cols <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols">
<br>
<button onclick="generate()" type="button" id="button">Generate</button>
<button onclick="removeTable()" type="reset" value="reset">RESET TABLE</button>

<table id="generatedTable" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using the id "generatedTable" in a confusing way, at the same time for the newly generated table and for the table you already had in your html file. And at the end you were removing the wrapper table instead of the newly generated one.

It is maybe easier to understand if you use a target element and add the table in it:

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('table-wrapper');

function generate() {
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.id = 'generatedTable';
  table.border = '1';

  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  var rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;
  var cols = document.getElementById("cols").value;

  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {

    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');

      td.width = 10;
      td.height = 10;

      var cellID = "cell [" + x + ", " + y + "]";
      td.setAttribute("id", cellID.toString());

      td.addEventListener("click", function() {
        cellClicked(this);
      });

      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + x + "," + y));

      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    wrapper.appendChild(table);
  }

  //document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;


}

function cellClicked(cell) {

  //var cell = document.getElementById("this");
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";


}

function mouseOver(cell) {
  var cell = document.getElementById("td");
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function mouseOut(cell) {
  var cell = document.getElementById("generatedTable");
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function removeTable() {
  var removeTab = document.getElementById('generatedTable');
  wrapper.removeChild(removeTab);

}
```

```html
No. of Rows <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows">
<br>
<br> No. of Cols <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols">
<br>
<button onclick="generate()" type="button" id="button">Generate</button>
<button onclick="removeTable()" type="reset" value="reset">RESET TABLE</button>

<div id="table-wrapper"></div>
```